# fetch запрос POST

Tags: javascript, java, post, fetch

```
@Override
    public void AddCategory(Category category) {
        budgetPlanerRepository.AddCategory(category);
    }

@Override
    public void AddCategory(String name, int budget) {
        budgetPlanerRepository.AddCategory(name,budget);
    }
```

---

Конструктор в классе Category:

```
@JsonCreator
    public Category(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("budget") int budget) {
        setName(name);
        setBudget(budget);
    }
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            path = "/categories",
            consumes = "application/json"
    )
    public void addCategory(@RequestBody Category category)
    {
        budgetPlanerService.AddCategory(category);
    }
```

Бекэндер написал данный код, подскажите как отправить POST запрос используя fetch. Вот пример, того что я пытался сделать:

```
fetch(baseUrl + '/categories', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'name' : split[0],
            'budget' : split[1]
        })
    })
```

split - массив в котором в 0 значение хранится имя, в 1-ом сумма.
ошибка которую выводит при попытке запроса (№400)

> error: "Bad Request"
>   message: "Missing request attribute 'category' of type Category"
>   path: "/categories"
>   status: 400
>   timestamp: "2019-02-01T21:47:36.239+0000"
>   Так же он показал, что он вводит и у него работает.
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я все равно не понимаю как написать POST запрос использую fetch.

Comment: Вы уже написали POST-запрос используя fetch. Какой ещё параметр нужно передать надо выяснить у автора API

Comment: @AlexeyTen проблема в том, что запрос не работает, еще параметр указывается в ошибке ('category' of type Category" ). Скорее требуется создать класс category с полями name, budget и отправлять объект класса и это все в js (то есть никак).

Comment: Запрос работает. 400 отдаёт сервер которому не нравятся переданные данные. Какие данные он ожидает мы тут не знаем и знать не можем. Обратитесь к документации сервера или его автору.

Comment: О, я подозреваю, что `split[1]` это строка, а должно быть целое число.

Comment: @AlexeyTen у меня есть доступ к файлам автора, но проблема в том, что сам автор спит, и я не знаю  где можно найти, какие данные требуется. А так же я залил скрин на котором автор (сам автор) передает данные и у него они передаются. Но я не понимаю, как такой синтаксис соблюдать в js

Comment: @AlexeyTen я уже пытался передать Number - безуспешно